# finding all number depending on the content of the previous line with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to find all numbers appearing in a large string. The matching numbers need to be followed by `平方米` and the string above the line which would hold the number has to match `土地面积：` :

```
<tr>
<th>土地面积：</th>
<td>10000平方米</td>
</tr>
```

How can I do this with regex in Python?

Comment: [Something like this](https://regex101.com/r/Ub3Mha/1) ?

Comment: hmmm, doesn't seem to work in Python: re.findall(r"(?<=土地面积: <\/th>\n<td>)\d+(?=平方米)",str) am I missing something? I should probably mention it needs to be implemented in Python...

Comment: Check my answer, I missed the `：` character which followed `土地面积`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
(?<=土地面积：<\/th>\n<td>)\d+(?=平方米)
```

- `(?<=土地面积：<\/th>\n<td>)` Lookbehind for literal substring `土地面积：`, followed by `</th>`, followed by newline and `<td>`.
- `\d+` Matches digits.
- `(?=平方米)` Positive lookahead for `平方米` substring.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ub3Mha/2).

---

In Python:

```
import re

mystr = '''
<tr>
<th>土地面积：</th>
<td>10000平方米</td>
</tr>
'''

print(re.findall(r'(?<=土地面积：<\/th>\n<td>)\d+(?=平方米)',mystr))
```

Prints:

```
['10000']
```